# AIX C++ iconv conversion fails

Tags: c++, ibm-mq, aix, utf, xms

I am using c++/XMS on AIX for consuming incoming messages from MQ.  Rightnow I have a need for converting the message from ISO8859-1 to UTF-8.  I do the following.

======================================================

```
void iso2utf8( char* text_iso, char* text_utf8, int nLen)
{
    cout << "Converting to UTF-8." << endl;
    iconv_t ic;
    ic = iconv_open("UTF-8", "ISO8859-1"); // iso->utf8
    cout << "Size of text_iso" << sizeof(text_iso) << endl;

    size_t il = nLen;
    size_t ol = nLen;

    cout << "Size of text_iso" << ol << endl;
    iconv(ic , &text_iso, &il, &text_utf8, &ol);
    iconv_close(ic);

    cout << "Message in UTF-8: " << text_utf8 << endl;

    return;
}
```

======================================================

After conversion, when I save the message into a file, I get back the ISO8859-1 message.  Any tips on how to solve this.  I use fstream to write to file.

Comment: You have a total lack of error checking in your code - all those iconv* calls can fail - you should be checking the result from each (error gives a result of -1 and sets `errno`) - that way you at least get a clue as to why your code is not working.

Comment: It does work for me (both with built-in iconv and GNU-iconv), so I suggest you create a mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  OK.  I make appropriate changes and revert soon.

Comment: Mind you, using 'nLen' for both input and output is bad idea: utf8 is usually longer than iso-8859-1, as 0x80..0xff codes become 2-byte sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You should write "ISO-8859-1" instead of "ISO8859-1"

Link to iconv man:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv_open.3.html

Citation:
The values permitted for fromcode and tocode and the supported combinations are system dependent. For the libiconv library, the following encodings are supported, in all combinations.

European languages

ASCII, ISO−8859−{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,13,14,15,16} ...